# VueJS - Generating html string of a component in computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm looking for a suggestion regarding a cleaner approach to generate a component data as html string and to pass it raw through the props of the component.

```
component-a.js
import componentB from './component-b'  



computed: {
  tooltipHTML() {
    render "<componentB :name='user1'/>
  }
}
```

I would prefer something similar to the above idea.

Answer (score 2):

Generating HTML  in a computed property and passing it as props to another component to be rendered in that component will not work.

What you are looking for is [Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots)

Since the complete code is not provided I guess you wanted to render `<componentB :name='user1'/>` inside another component( a tooltip component)

You would be doing it as follows using slots:

```
<tooltip-comp>
    <componentB :name='user1'/>
</tooltip-comp>
```

In your tooltip component

```
//tooltip component

<template>
    <div class="my-tooltip">
        <p>my tooltip</p>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```